# How does linux decide which core a thread runs on?

Tags: linux, scheduling

I know the linux decides which cores threads run on, therefore, the tasks of each core are guaranteed to be balanced. But where can I see the introductory documentation?

I would like to understand the specific implementation

-----2022-2-14----

The schedule algorithm is all about scheduling strategy, rarely how to allocate and migrate threads in process, I know there is thread steal technology, similar to the implementation of go.

Most operating system books only talk about processes and threads, but how to schedule on multiple cores is also omitted.

Comment: Doesn't `<path_to_source>/linux/Documentation/scheduler/*` help?

Comment: You have to read kernel code to fully understand.

Comment: Or as [web pages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/).

Comment: I will read the above documentation and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that when a core has cache for a process, the kernel tries to reschedule the thread on the same core, but this is not guaranteed, and it could be rescheduled to run on any available core usually.   The kernel, for example, typically will alternate scheduling a process between the primary thread and secondary thread in a core, so that if the core is saturated, the process is not starved in the secondary thread.

However, it is also possible for a thread to request that it only be scheduled to run on a specific set of cores.  A process might request this if it knows that there will be cache issues, but more frequently it is done when a specific socket has access to specific I/O devices that the process needs access to, and cross socket I/O would be expensive.

One example of this would be accessing a GPU in a PCI slot that is mapped to a specific cpu socket.